# how can I assert boolean in Jasmine using "toHaveBeenCalledWith"

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine

I am trying to assert a function is called with:

```
expect(functionA).toHaveBeenCalledWith(xxx, yyyy, true);
```

i do not care what is xxx and yyyy, i only care the last parameter is true.

How can I do it in Jasmine? I tried:

```
expect(functionA).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.objectContaining(true));
```

while true is not an object.

I also tried:

```
expect(functionA.calls.mostRecent().args[2]).toMatch(true);
```

but it gives me errors:

```
Error:<toMatch>:Expected is not a String or a RegExp
```

how should I assert it? I am new to Jasmine, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming xxx and yyyy are string, you can do:

```
expect(functionA).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.any(String), jasmine.any(String), true);
```

also see the documentation: [official docs](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction#section-Matching_Anything_with_%3Ccode%3Ejasmine.any%3C/code%3E)